# How to call a model method from a system plugin?

Tags: component, plugin, model

I have a component ('com_foo') which has a model called '**foobar**'. The class declaration is like this:

```
class FooModelbar extends JModelItem
```

This class has a public method called **getFooBar()**.

I also have a system plugin called 'foobar'. I am trying to access the public method of the component from this plugin.

```
JLoader::register('FooModelBar', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_foo/models/bar.php');
$foobarInstance = new FooModelBar();
$baz = $foobarInstance->getFoobar();
```

But I am getting some unrelated errors like 'Cannot redeclare function x' which is not even in the plugin or the component. And if I turn off the plugin or remove the JLoader::register line of code, the error disappears. So clearly I must be doing something wrong.

What is the 'correct' way to access a component's method from a system plugin?

Comment: Could you please post your code here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work with ease in Joomla 3.x

```
//load model
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'components' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'com_foo' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'models');

//get instance of model class, where class name will be fooModelBar
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('bar', 'fooModel');

//call model method
$baz = $model->getFoobar();
```

Answer (score 4):

To call a model from anywhere inside Joomla you can use this method

```
//Load the Joomla Model framework
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');

//Load com_foo's foobar model. Remember the file name should be foobar.php inside the models folder
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_foo/models', 'FooModelBar');

//Get Instance of Model Object
$foobarInstance = JModelLegacy::getInstance('foobar', 'FooModelBar');

//Now you can call the methods inside the model
$baz = $foobarInstance->getFoobar();
```